# Get the element after/before the matched one in json with jq

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have the following json input to the jq command:

```
[
  {"type":"dog",  "set":"foo"},
  {"type":"bird", "set":"bar"},
  {"type":"cat",  "set":"blaz"},
  {"type":"fish", "set":"mor"}
]
```

I know that there is an element in this array whose `type` is "bird", in this case, the second element.  But I want its next (or previous) sibling, that is, the element after (before) it, in this case, the third (first) element.  How can I get it in jq?

Also, I have another question: If the matched element (that is, the element whose value of `type` I know) is the last one in the array, I want it to get the first one as next (that is, cycle through the array) instead of returning nothing. The same whether the matched element is the first one (then I want to get the last element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me also offer you an alternative solution, based on a walk-path unix tool for JSON: **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)** - there you "encode" your query logic right into the path:

e.g. to find a `"type":"bird"` record and then it's preceding sibling (in the parent's array) would be like this:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[type]:<bird> [-1]<idx>k [-1]>idx<t-1' -r
{ "set": "foo", "type": "dog" }
```

let me break it down for you:

- `[type]:<bird>` - will find recursively a record `"type":"bird"`
- `[-1]<idx>k` - will step up 1 tier in JSON tree (select parent, effectively select the entire record `{"type":"bird", "set":"bar"}`) and will memorize its array index into the namespace `idx`
- `[-1]>idx<t-1` - will again step up 1 level in JSON (selecting the top array) and will search (non-recursively) for the entry with index (stored in `idx`) offset by `-1`

Equally once can select a next sibling:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[type]:<bird>[-1]<idx>k[-1]>idx<t1'
{ "set": "blaz", "type": "cat" }
```

Or, select the first entry (based on the last match):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[type]:<fish>[-1]<idx>k[-1]>idx<t-1000' -r
{ "set": "foo", "type": "dog" }
```

(just put some surely low value as the relative quantifier - it'll get normalized to the first entry)

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool

Comment: Thanks, that is a very utile tool.  I was using jq to print the entries, one per line, then using the Unix text manipulation commands to get the following or preceding line to the one I matched.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of specificity, let's suppose you want to extract the the `(before, focus, after)` triple as an array, where `before` and `after` wrap around as described. For simplicity, let's also suppose the source array is of length at least 2.

Next, for ease of exposition and understanding, we will define a helper function for extracting the three items:

```
# $i is assumed to be a valid index into the input array,
# which is assumed to be of length at least 2
def triple($i):
  if $i == 0 then [last] + .[0:2]
  elif $i == (length-1) then .[$i-1: $i+2] + [first]
  else .[$i-1: $i+2]
  end;
```

Now we have only to find the index, and use it:

```
(map(.type) | index("bird")) as $i
| if $i then triple($i) else empty end
```

Using this approach, other variants can easily be obtained.